# Returning JSON message in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have written a PHP script to connect to a MySQL database and extract some information. I know that the majority of the script is working as it actually inserts a MAC address into the table (which is what it should do when the value of the MAC address in the DB table is NULL).

However, the resulting message from my script is "**No license found (3)".**

My question is, how can it be returning this message if it's inserting a MAC address? The `else` statement would only be entered if `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` returned false.

What I want is for the MAC address to be checked (or inserted if NULL in the DB) and to return the message "Licensed".

Apologies for the nested `if/else` statements.

```
<?php

// Array for JSON response.
$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// Check for GET data.
if (isset($_GET["LicenseKey"]) 
        && isset($_GET["SoftwareId"]) 
        && isset($_GET["MacAddress"])) {

    $licenseKey = $_GET['LicenseKey'];
    $softwareId = $_GET['SoftwareId'];
    $macAddress = $_GET['MacAddress'];

    // Import database connection variables.
    require_once __DIR__ . '/get_license_SQL.php';

    $query = SQL_GET_LICENSE;
    $query = str_replace("%1", $softwareId, $query);
    $query = str_replace("%2", $licenseKey, $query);

    $result = mysqli_query($db->connect(), $query);

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // Check for empty result.
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // Get the result.
            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $license = array();
            $license["ExpiryDate"] = $result["ExpiryDate"];

            // Check if MAC address exists.
            $query = SQL_GET_MAC_ADDRESS;
            $query = str_replace("%1", $licenseKey, $query);
            $result = mysqli_query($db->connect(), $query);

            if (!empty($result)) {
                $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                echo json_encode($result);

                if ($result["MacAddress"] == $macAddress
                        || $result["MacAddress"] == NULL) {

                    // Device MAC address matches MAC address on record. 
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["license"] = array();

                    if ($result["MacAddress"] == NULL) {    
                        // Insert new MAC address into the database.
                        $query = SQL_INSERT_MAC_ADDRESS;
                        $query = str_replace("%1", $macAddress, $query);
                        $query = str_replace("%2", $licenseKey, $query);                
                        mysqli_query($db->connect(), $query);
                    }

                    // Add MAC address to license array.
                    $license["MacAddress"] = $result["MacAddress"];
                    $response["message"] = "Licensed";
                    array_push($response["license"], $license);
                    echo json_encode($response);    
                } else {
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "License has already been used by another device";
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
            } else {
                $response["success"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "No license found (2)";
                array_push($response["license"], $license);
                echo json_encode($response);
            }           
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No license found (3)";
            array_push($response["license"], $license);
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No license found (4)";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

db_connect.php :

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {

    function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    function connect() {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con, DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error()) or die(mysqli_error());
        return $con;
    }
}
?>
```

get_license_SQL.php :

```
<?php
define('SQL_GET_LICENSE', "SELECT licenses.ExpiryDate
        FROM licenses
        WHERE licenses.SoftwareId=%1 AND licenses.LicenseKey=%2");

define('SQL_GET_MAC_ADDRESS', "SELECT licenses.MacAddress
        FROM licenses
        WHERE licenses.LicenseKey=%1");

define('SQL_INSERT_MAC_ADDRESS', "UPDATE licenses 
        SET MacAddress=%1 
        WHERE licenses.LicenseKey=%2");
?>
```

Comment: The response **No license found (3)** means the Mac address does not exist in the database. The code to insert the Mac address into the database will never be run, that's your bug, hence it will keep repeating the same response. PS: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that there are no results from the SQL_GET_LICENSE query? Even though there are as it then proceedes to insert a MAC address.... How would no matching MAC address reach that else statement containing "No license found(3)"?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Could you please explain how it is vulnerable to injection? Thank you!

Comment: SQL-injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because you don't bind parameters into your SQL queries. You use `str_replace()`, but you should at least be using `real_escape_string()` or, better, use a prepared statement and bind: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I'll look into those.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following lines of code

```
                if ($result["MacAddress"] == NULL) {    
                    // Insert new MAC address into the database.
                    $query = SQL_INSERT_MAC_ADDRESS;
                    $query = str_replace("%1", $macAddress, $query);
                    $query = str_replace("%2", $licenseKey, $query);                
                    mysqli_query($db->connect(), $query);
                }

                // Add MAC address to license array.
                $license["MacAddress"] = $result["MacAddress"];
```

You are running the following query but you are not storing the result in a variable after insertion in the database:
        mysqli_query($db->connect(), $query);

In the following line the $result array has the old values from the database which were fetched prior to insertion. Please try to store the values in a variable and use that variable after the insertion.
         $license["MacAddress"] = $result["MacAddress"];

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how this answers the question. Even if I store this result, why would it be entering the `else` statement containing `$response["message"] = "No license found (3)";` ? Thanks!